# Regular databinding seems to disable triggers

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, triggers

I just came across another problem with WPF.

I have a collection of custom controls (composite ones; made of a border inside a grid etc.).

I'm controlling their `Background` color via triggers as well as binding. I want them to get a bit darker on a mouseover (achieved by triggers and a custom `IValueConverter`), but also to change color when select (that is, clicked on). The latter is done by a regular `Setter`.

```
<Grid Width="150" Height="50" Margin="5">
    <Border CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.5" >
        <Border.Resources>
            <local:BackgroundConverter x:Key="ColorConverter"/>
        </Border.Resources>
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">                    
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Grid.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=MyStatus, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Grid.IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=MyStatus, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=MyStatus, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"/>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <Grid>                
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.6*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>                                
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontSize="14" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold">                    
                <Label Foreground="{Binding Path=TextColor}" Content="{Binding Path=ID}"/>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" FontSize="9" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0" Padding="0">
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=StockName}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

The mouseover effect works correctly until I click one of the controls. Triggers stop working at that point (apart from the controls that haven't been clicked on).

I'm a bit baffled. How can I put binding to some use without disabling the triggers?

I'll supply more details if necessary.

---

@Rachel

> Can you post your converter code later on? I don't see how the
>   IsMouseOver property is getting passed to the converter, so it's
>   probably a static value that's not updated when it changes. And since
>   the value doesn't change when it's triggered, its likely not bothering
>   to re-evaluate the value. You might be better off using a
>   IMutliValueConverter and passing it IsMouseOver and MyStatus, so it
>   gets reevaluated anytime either of those two values change

I didn't use a `IMultiValueConverter`. For that purpose I created my own "composite" object that includes `IsMouseOver`. This is necessary because the background color is supposed to be calculated both out of my own data (whether an item is selected, or mapped) as well as the mouse over (whatever the background color, it's supposed to darken slightly on a mouse over).

**Converter code:**

```
public class BackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("BackgroundConverter.Convert()");
        if (!(value is StockViewBackgroundStatus))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("value");
        }
        var casted = (StockViewBackgroundStatus)value;
        if (casted.IsNone)
        {
            if (casted.IsMouseOver)
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
            }
            else
            {
                return CreateLinearGradient(Colors.Gray, false);
            }
        }
        switch (casted.Status)
        {
            case StockItem.Status.Mapped:
                {
                    return CreateLinearGradient(Color.FromRgb(83, 165, 18), casted.IsMouseOver);
                }
            case StockItem.Status.MappedElsewhere:
                {
                    return CreateLinearGradient(Color.FromRgb(104, 189, 36), casted.IsMouseOver);
                }
            case StockItem.Status.NotMapped:
                {
                    return CreateLinearGradient(Colors.LightGray, casted.IsMouseOver);
                }
            default:
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException(casted.Status.ToString());
                }
        }            
    }

    private static LinearGradientBrush CreateLinearGradient(Color initial, bool darker)
    {
        var darkened = darker ? 0.1 : 0;
        return new LinearGradientBrush(
            Lighten(initial, 1.05 - darkened),
            Lighten(initial, 0.95 - darkened), 
            90);
    }

    private static Color Lighten(Color initial, double factor)
    {
        Func<double, double> trunc = (value) => (Math.Max(0, Math.Min(255, value)));
        var resulting = Color.FromRgb(
            System.Convert.ToByte(trunc(initial.R * factor)),
            System.Convert.ToByte(trunc(initial.G * factor)),
            System.Convert.ToByte(trunc(initial.B * factor)));
        return resulting;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("BackgroundConverter.ConvertBack()");
        return value;
    }
}
```

**`StockItem` object**

```
public partial class StockItem : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _empty;
    public StockItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private string _id;
    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ID");
        }

    }

    public Brush TextColor
    {
        get
        {                
            Color color = IsSelected ? Colors.White : Colors.Black;
            return new SolidColorBrush(color);
        }
    }

    private string _stockName;
    public string StockName
    {
        get
        {
            return _stockName;
        }
        set
        {
            _stockName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("StockName");
        }
    }

    StockViewBackgroundStatus _status;
    public StockViewBackgroundStatus MyStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return new StockViewBackgroundStatus()
            {
                IsMouseOver = this.IsMouseOver,
                IsNone = IsEmpty,
                Status = MappingStatus
            };
        }
        set
        {
            _status = value;
            Debug.WriteLine("in " + ID + "...");
            Debug.WriteLine("RaisePropertyChanged(\"IsMouseOver\")");
            Debug.WriteLine("RaisePropertyChanged(\"MyStatus\")");

            RaisePropertyChanged("IsMouseOver"); // added, but doesn't help
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyStatus");
        }
    }

    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get
        {
            return _empty;
        }
    }

    public static StockItem EmptyStock
    {
        get
        {
            return new StockItem()
            {
                _empty = true,
                ID = "none",
                Name = String.Empty
            };
        }
    }

    internal EventHandler Selected
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private Status _mappingStatus;
    public Status MappingStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return _mappingStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            _mappingStatus = value;
            Debug.WriteLine("in " + ID + "...");
            Debug.WriteLine("RaisePropertyChanged(\"MappingStatus\")");
            Debug.WriteLine("RaisePropertyChanged(\"TextColor\")");
            RaisePropertyChanged("MappingStatus");
            RaisePropertyChanged("TextColor");

            MyStatus = new StockViewBackgroundStatus() { IsMouseOver = this.IsMouseOver, IsNone = _empty, Status = value };                

            if (value == Status.Mapped && Selected != null)
            {
                Selected(this, null);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return MappingStatus == Status.Mapped;
        }
    }

    public enum Status
    {            
        Mapped,
        MappedElsewhere,
        NotMapped
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**The view class encapsulating the collection** (the one that I'm actually setting as the `DataContext`)

```
public class TargetStocks
{
    public ObservableCollection<StockItem> AllStocks
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void Add(StockItem sv, EventHandler selected)
    {
        if (sv == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("sv");
        }
        sv.MouseDown += sv_MouseDown;
        if (selected != null)
        {
            sv.Selected += selected;
        }
        if (AllStocks == null)
        {
            AllStocks = new ObservableCollection<StockItem>();
        }
        AllStocks.Add(sv);
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<StockItem> stocks, EventHandler selected)
    {
        foreach (var stock in stocks)
        {
            Add(stock, selected);
        }
    }

    void sv_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(sender is StockItem))
        {
            return;
        }
        var sv = (StockItem)sender;
        foreach (StockItem stock in AllStocks)
        {
            if (stock.MappingStatus == StockItem.Status.Mapped)
            {
                // this seems to kill the trigger
                stock.MappingStatus = StockItem.Status.NotMapped;
            }
            if (stock == sv && sv.MappingStatus != StockItem.Status.Mapped)
            {
                // as above
                stock.MappingStatus = StockItem.Status.Mapped;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What happens, as shown by debugging, is that prior to clicking any of the stock items (or before the `MappingStatus` of any of them is changed) the mouseover effect works without triggering the converter at all.

`Convert` is not called at all.

It's setting the `MappingStatus` in the `MouseDown` event handler that seems to disable (or detach) the trigger.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the Click code that changes the background color? Also, is your `Click` event setting the source property in the binding, or the `Background` property of the border? If it's the 2nd, [Depdencey Property Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) dictates that values set on the object itself take precedence over styled or triggered values.

Comment: As @Rachel asks - what is your `Click` doing?

Comment: Also maybe I'm missing something, but don't your Triggers all return the same value? They both set `Status` to `{Binding Path=MyStatus, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}`, which also is the same value as the default `Setter`, so your Background color will remain static regardless of if the mouse is over it or not...

Comment: @Rachel @XAMeLi the `Click` is resetting `MyStatus` (raising `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event) of all child items (all of them, as when the clicked one gets selected, the rest is thereby unselected)

Comment: @Rachel - the converter takes `IsMouseOver` property into account. Thanks to that it initially works. The thing is that the triggers are disabled (?) and from that point the converter is not used anymore (verified by debugging the code).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not at work anymore (can't supply more code atm)

Comment: @KonradMorawski Can you post your converter code later on? I don't see how the `IsMouseOver` property is getting passed to the converter, so it's probably a static value that's not updated when it changes. And since the value doesn't change when it's triggered, its likely not bothering to re-evaluate the value. You might be better off using a `IMutliValueConverter` and passing it `IsMouseOver` and `MyStatus`, so it gets reevaluated anytime either of those two values change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings don't get re-evaluated as a result of a normal trigger firing.

You can change the property to a new binding object, however the bindings itself only gets evaluated the first time it's used as a result of the trigger.

So when your `IsMouseOver` property changes, the `Background` property is changing from one `Binding` object to another `Binding` object, however the binding itself is not getting re-evaluated.

If you raise a PropertyChange notification on the bound value though, the binding *will* get re-evaluated.

As a test, add a `Debug` line or breakpoint to your converter, and test it with triggering a `PropertyChanged` notification on the bound value. You'll see it gets hit when it receives a change notification and re-evaluates.

If you want a bound value to be evaluated when one of multiple properties change, use an [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx).

Comment: back from holidays; I updated my question accordingly. Thanks for help :(

Comment: @KonradMorawski Thanks. Based on your code, you should definitely consider switching to an `IMultiValueConverter`, as bindings don't get reevaluated if the `IsMouseOver` or `MappingStatus` changes, or if the `MyStatus` value doesn't actually change to a new value. You can create an `IMultiValueConverter` that accepts both the `IsMouseOver` property from the UI, and the `MappingStatus` and `IsSelected` properties from the data.

Comment: thanks, I'll try that. But why does it (currently) work properly only until clicked?

Comment: @KonradMorawski It only evaluates the bound value once the first time the trigger occurs, and caches the result of that. Moving your mouse over stores ColorA and moving it off stores ColorB, so the color will change when moving back and forth over it without re-evaluating the converter, but when you trigger a `PropertyChange` notification on `MyStatus` in the `Click` event, both bindings get re-evaluated and the cached value for both triggers is updated to the `IsMouseOver` color, since the mouse is over the item at the time it's clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll go and try with `IMultiValueConverter`. Answer accepted